# Word-based Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

It is often the last thing one reads,
But the most a person can have in a month is two.
The table has seven, but the longest game has lasted nine.
History has many, but a sentence one at most.

What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is a great riddle - I hope to see you around here a lot more!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are:

> A period

**Reasoning:**

It is often the last thing one reads,

> A period ends a sentence

But the most a person can have in a month is two.

> I think this refers to the menstrual cycle a.k.a. period

The table has seven,

> The periodic table has 7 periods

but the longest game has lasted nine.

> The longest hockey game had six overtimes (the normal game being 3 periods) and it was [Montreal Maroons vs. Detroit Red Wings](http://www.hockeyinsideout.com/news/celebrating-nhls-longest-game-played-march-24-25-1936)

History has many,

> History has many time periods

but a sentence one at most.

> A sentence has one period at most (not technically true but I think that was what the asker intended)

Comment: I was thinking this, but I found a hockey game that went 10 periods :-(

Answer (score -2):

```
A full stop. Took me a while too figure out that m because you say period which fits the rest.
```

Comment: This is the same thing as the accepted answer: a period is the American English way of referring to a full stop.